# Navigation Property Mapping on two different fields

Tags: entity-framework, fluent

I have a squirrely situation, where in some relationships a tables `ID` field is used as the key reference.  But in other, older implementations, the `Name` field was used as the relationship mapping.

```
FileType:
ID | Name |....

FileTypeDetails:
ID | FileTypeId | ....

PostingGroupDetails :
FileType | ....
```

`PostingGroupDetails.FileType` has a map to `FileType.Name`.  `FileTypeDetails.FileTypeId` maps to `FileType.ID`.

I am using the Fluent API structure to do the mappings manually but am running into a wall with this relationship mapping.

I though that doing a multi-key mapping might work but am unsure.  Still in the design stage, and about to implement the interface side of the project.

Any ideas on how i make the mapping available to both, until we can consolidate the relationship mapping to one or the other?

## EF Implementation:

### FileType

I know `FileType` is currently Optional, but its only a direct correlation to the Table design.  I am flagging it for schema updating, currently in practice it is a required field in order for the entry to be submitted.

```
ToTable( "FileType" , "Int" );

HasKey( ftd => ftd.ID );
Property( ftd => ftd.ID ).HasColumnName( "ID" )
    .HasDatabaseGeneratedOption( DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity );
Property( ftd => ftd.Name).HasColumnName( "Name" )
    .IsOptional();
//Navigation Properties
HasMany( ftd => ftd.FileNames )
    .WithRequired( fn => fn.FileType );
HasMany( ftd => ftd.PostingGroupDetails )
    .WithRequired( pgd => pgd.FileTypeDetails );
```

### FileNames

`FileNames.FileTypeID` relates to `FileType.ID`

```
ToTable( "FileNames" , "Int" );

HasKey( fn => fn.ID );
Property( fn => fn.ID ).HasColumnName( "ID" )
    .HasDatabaseGeneratedOption( DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity );
Property( fn => fn.FileTypeID ).HasColumnName( "FileTypeID" )
    .IsRequired();
//Navigation Properties
HasRequired( fn => fn.FileType )
    .WithMany( ftd => ftd.FileNames )
    .HasForeignKey( fn => fn.FileTypeID );
```

### PostingGroupDetails

`PostingGroupDetails.FileType` relates to `FileType.Name`

```
ToTable( "PostingGroupDetails " , "Int" );

HasKey( pgd => pgd.ID );
Property( pgd => pgd.ID ).HasColumnName( "ID" )
    .HasDatabaseGeneratedOption( DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity );
//Required Properties
Property( pgd => pgd.FileType ).HasColumnName( "FileType" )
    .IsRequired();

//Navigation Properties
HasRequired( pgd => pgd.FileTypeDetails )
    .WithMany( ftd => ftd.PostingGroupDetails );
```

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated.  Refactoring the Database structure is not an option right now, but it is on the plate to be done.

Comment: Do the older tables (like PostingGroupDetails) have primary keys?

Comment: Not necessarily.  I am in the redev stage, so in the future i will do it properly.  But right now i have to design with existing design patterns, while also prepping for "proper" design patterns.  All of them have Identity Fields but they did not declare them as PK, consistently.  Although the `FileType.Name` field references are Unique, but no UK index was declared.

Comment: You'll have to choose which fields you want to mark as PK in the class model. You can only define associations to PKs that are known by EF and there can only be one PK per entity. So for `FileType` you must either take `ID` or `Name` and then you can define an association with `FileTypeDetails` *or* `PostingGroupDetails`. For the other associations you know exist you'll have to write join queries.

Comment: So hard map the ones that goto the PK.  For the others dont define a Navigation Property, but instead use the LINQ framework to obtain it by name.  I assume that is what your talking about?  Something like `Entity.Where(ft => ft.Name == name)`?

Comment: Yes, that's basically it, or `join y from Y on x.Name equals y.Name`.

Comment: @GertArnold If you could provide that as the answer ill mark you +1 answer ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Entity Framework allows for differences between the database model and the class model (or conceptual model). You can define primary keys in the conceptual model that don't exist, or aren't even constrained as unique, in the data model.

So you can (and have to) choose which fields you want to mark as PK in the conceptual model. You can only define associations to PKs that are defined in the conceptual model and there can only be one PK per entity. So for `FileType` you must either take `ID` or `Name` and then you can define an association with `FileTypeDetails` *or* `PostingGroupDetails`. For the other associations you know exist you'll have to write join queries. As in

```
from x in X
join y from Y on x.Name equals y.Name
select ...
```